# Twitter Bootstrap navbar-fixed-top repositioning on page

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I've gotten Bootstrap running on my site successfully but I'm trying to use the navbar-top-fixed functionality and whenever the page loads it pushes everything down about 20 pixels and I can't seem to diagnose why.

My code for the nav-bar is this:

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container protected">
                <ul class="nav pull-right nav-pills">
                    <li><a href="/account/login" id="customer_login_link">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/cart"><i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-white"></i> View cart <span class="badge badge-warning">2</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the page at [this link](http://www.athousandprints.com) will load the page properly, and then when it loads the page it pushes it down like [this screenshot](http://cl.ly/2v1b1M2Q1E1s0k2j183k).

Has anyone seen this before or know any quick fixes? I am customizing one of the nav-bars on the page using lessCSS.

Answer (score 0):

Please move the navbar markup in front of the "container" div. The "container" class has this margin defined.

See here: http://postimage.org/image/nu5pv8tkz/

Comment: Thanks for your response, but after doing this it still doesn't fix the problem. Any way to diagnose where the extra margin px are coming from beyond Firebug?

Comment: I highly recommend Google Chrome and it's developer tools. Just put in all the code that you want to be there and navigate through and you will be able to easily see what's pushing it down.